# Is there a way to trigger a Postgres function whenever a new file is uploaded on S3 bucket?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

I have a function on Postgres that imports data from my AWS-S3 bucket.
Is there a way to trigger that function whenever a new file is uploaded to the bucket?

p.s. my Postgres database is running on AWS RDS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, You can create AWS lambda function and add events in your s3 bucket to trigger lambda function whenever object gets uploaded in s3 bucket and then call that postgres function from aws lambda function.

follow the tutorial for more info
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/aws_lambda/aws_lambda_using_lambda_function_with_amazon_s3.htm

Comment: Since your lambda function need to have access on RDS database which is usually in private subnet. you need to put lambda function in VPC to connect with RDS.

Comment: Connect lambda function with S3 via VPC endpoint, So create VPC gateway endpoint for s3 for vpc which you put in lambda function